# What are the rules for deviation from the Subject–Verb–Object rule?

Tags: word-order

English is taught as a strict Subject–Verb–Object, but I have seen quite a few exceptions to this rule. I noticed that I really enjoy such exceptions; one of my favourite ones is this phrase:

> – Off you go!
>
> And off she went.

This probably can be understood as "moving a word to the beginning as a way to emphasise". In this case the Subject is right next to the opening word. Other examples of Subject having the second place would be (sorry, no good quotes come to mind in this hour, so I'm half-googling them, half-making these up and so may be making mistakes):

> Usually I didn't wonder at all whether spaghetti could talk.
>
> Rich as you may be, you can't buy sincere friends.

There're other possibilities, however, with the Verb remaining on the second place:

> Seldom have I read such a good book.
>
> Foolish were my attempts to contest the rule.

I thought this was just a matter of taste until learning German, in which you can move almost anything at the beginning of the sentence, provided that you always keep the Verb on the second place. Maybe there's a norm after all: what are the rules?

Comment: Not quite a "strict Subject–Verb–Object". So the question is a NARQ.

Comment: Well it's indeed taught as one, and if it's not quite that, I'd appreciate if you elaborated on that instead of dismissing the question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks! That could be a good source of examples, but there's unfortunately no explanation for the particular choices

Comment: English _may_, as you say, be taught as a strict S-V-O language, but I'd avoid those teachers claiming that it is.

Comment: Yes there is: **SVO is the ground state. Deviations from this (and other norms) by syntactic rules are used to form variant clause and phrase types, to indicate focussed elements, to express emotions, and to improve parseability. Depending on the rules, of course. –  John Lawler** For a more detailed analysis, you need a decent book on grammar.

Comment: And what are these rules?

Comment: I changed the title of the question to emphasise the difference from the one in the box

Comment: English may indeed also have O-S-V. "Ten people, I counted."

Emphatic adverbs and conjunctions as well as negative ones have also been observed to retain O-V-S order: http://ge.tt/9XDMW4C1/v/0

The article doesn't conclusively restrict the domain in which that can happen.

Comment: I.e. it's an iffy area, as Edwin said, it's only underlying SVO.

Comment: You also need to do some groundwork on what the terms subject (S) and object (O) actually mean before you look at the allowed permutations of S,V,O. There is no direct object in 'And off she went' and 'Foolish were all my attempts that day'. You need to study complements (C) and adjuncts (and indirect objects) before you can start analysing even simple sentences. After that, there are 855 threads here alone addressing 'sentence structure', including Yoda-ish OSV.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you for the valuable insight into the difficulties of obtaining linguistic knowledge

Comment: The sister website ELL is designed to address groundwork-type questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no common rule for deviation of Subject - Verb -Object rule. It depends on what type of sentence you are using/forming.E.g : Imperative, Interrogative, exclamatory are such examples where we do not use Subject - Verb -Object rule.
Eg:**Imperative sentence** uses Verb - subject/object rule,
   **Interrogative sentence** uses Verb - Subject - Object rule.

Comment: And we're avoiding mentioning the role and distribution of auxiliaries.